# create a dictionary using for loop after the matching pattern

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
sample file:-
=============
Remote Copy System Information
Status: Started, Normal

Group Information

Name                 Target     Status   Role       Mode     Options
hpux_tpvv_raw_st_pri s2228      Started  Secondary  Sync     auto_recover,auto_failover,path_management,auto_synchronize,active_active
  LocalVV        ID   RemoteVV                ID   SyncStatus    LastSyncTime
  ux_tpvv_pri.1 28541 hpux_tpvv_raw_st_pri.1 13506 Synced        NA
  ux_tpvv_pri.2 28542 hpux_tpvv_raw_st_pri.2 13507 Synced        NA
  ux_tpvv_pri.3 28543 hpux_tpvv_raw_st_pri.3 13508 Synced        NA
```

I need to create a dictionary after the occurrence of "LocalVV". I am not able to extract the lines after "LocalVV" and convert each line to dictionary on the go.

```
d = {'ux_tpvv_pri.1' : 'Synced', 'ux_tpvv_pri.2' : 'Synced', 'ux_tpvv_pri.3' : 'Synced'}
```

with this data, I can check for `d.values()` and if all are synced return true, else return the `key and value` if other than sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use pandas for this:

**Sample input:**

```
from io import StringIO
s = """Remote Copy System Information
Status: Started, Normal

Group Information

Name                 Target     Status   Role       Mode     Options
hpux_tpvv_raw_st_pri s2228      Started  Secondary  Sync     auto_recover,auto_failover,path_management,auto_synchronize,active_active
LocalVV        ID   RemoteVV                ID   SyncStatus    LastSyncTime
ux_tpvv_pri.1 28541 hpux_tpvv_raw_st_pri.1 13506 Synced        NA
ux_tpvv_pri.2 28542 hpux_tpvv_raw_st_pri.2 13507 Synced        NA
ux_tpvv_pri.3 28543 hpux_tpvv_raw_st_pri.3 13508 Synced        NA"""
```

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), skiprows=7, sep='\s+')

df.set_index('LocalVV')['SyncStatus'].to_dict()
```

**Output:**

```
{'ux_tpvv_pri.1': 'Synced',
 'ux_tpvv_pri.2': 'Synced',
 'ux_tpvv_pri.3': 'Synced'}
```